# How can I change background color only for selected days in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is my code for fullcalendar. Here how can I change background-color only for `feb 14`.

```
 dayRender: function (date, cell) {

         var Xmas = new Date('2017-02-14');
                    var weekday = Xmas.getDate();
                    console.log(weekday); 
                     if (weekday) {
                        cell.css("background-color", "red");
                    }

    }
```

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/z8Jfx/617/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in base of your demo [here is mine](http://jsfiddle.net/z8Jfx/619/), the idea is to use getTime, to obtain the milliseconds time to compare with xmash day.

```
var $calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },

    defaultView: 'month',

    dayRender: function (date, cell) {
        console.log(date.getTime())
         var Xmas = new Date('2017-02-14');
                    var weekday = Xmas.getTime();
                    console.log(weekday); 
                     if (weekday===date.getTime()) {
                        cell.css("background-color", "red");
                    }

    }   
});
```

Comment: if i try this, am getting `date.getTime is not a function` error.

Comment: also In your code bg has been changed for today date.I dont want to change background color for `today date`.

Comment: yea ok ok  :-) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sample of your request but this is the CSS only.. i make a code for feb 14 only.

```
.fc-day[data-date^="2017-11-14"] {
  background: blue !important;
}
```

maybe you can change the data date what do you want. but i created for you is not dynamic. i hope you appreciate it.

Or if you want a dynamic get all holidays or what date you want to highlight then use addClass.

Comment: if i need to change background color of one day(different dates) from every month then it wont work out right?

Comment: if you want a dynamic.. it won't work, I created is for static only.. but i can make dynamic..use jquery or javascript.. to add Class each date what you want to highlight..